# How to push my code safely to remote repository?

Tags: git, repository, push

I want to push my code to the remote repository, but:

- I haven't updated my local repository for a month
- I've added some code to the staging area but didn't commit the changes
- I've moved files to another directory in my workspace

What should I do if I want to push my code safely to the remote repository and also update my local repo and workspace?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to git pull to get the changes from remote into your local repo before you can push your local changes. If there are differences between remote and local you'll need to merge. This helped me: marklodato.github.io/visual-git-guide/index-en.html

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is getting your files up to your remote repository (and remove the ones that you've moved),

Open your local repository with terminal,

```
git pull
git add *
git commit -m "whatever you want to name this commit"
git push
```

and everythng will be up in your remote repository.